# How to get rid of the annoying error: No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.github.eclipsecolortheme,0.15.0.20140

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

today I have installed Eclipse and then I have installed the [Eclipse Color Theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme#.VEvjAZOUewE) plugin.
After that, everytime I start Eclipse I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried to reinstall the Eclipse Color Theme plugin, install it offline (downloading the .zip and unpacking it in the /dropins folder), but nothing, the error continues to pop up everytime Eclipse is started.

How can I get rid of this error once for all?